# Cant use Tkinter entry widget to hold down a key inputed by the user through a function

Tags: python, tkinter

im new to programing in general and im trying to  make a simple program using pyautogui and tkinter to make some basic automation in this case holding a specified key down.
However i dont understand what is the problem since the program compiles but nothing really happens
heres the code
(if u could guide me to some basic learning resources id also be gratefull)

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
from tkinter import *

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,1,1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,1,1)

def retrieve():
    hold(key_entry.get())
    print('here')

def hold(key_entry):
    pyautogui.press(key_entry)
    #print(key_entry)
    
    



 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x450")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

key_input_explanation = StringVar()
key_input_explanation.set("input the key u want to be held down. only input a singe key otherwise it wont work")

delay_input_explanation = StringVar()
delay_input_explanation.set("input the delay u want. only input a singe digit otherwise it wont work")
 

#explains the user what to input
label = Label(frame, textvariable = key_input_explanation )
label.pack()

#the user inputs the key to be held down
key_entry = Entry(frame, width = 1)
key_entry.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

#explains the user what to input
label = Label(frame, textvariable = delay_input_explanation )
label.pack()

#the user inputs the time before the key is held down
delay_entry = Entry(frame, width = 2)
delay_entry.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)


#the user must press this to send the info 
button = Button(frame, text = "Submit", command = retrieve)
button.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)


root.title("why wont this work ")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you believe the key is going to be sent?  If your application has the focus, then those keys are going to be sent to your application, and you are not looking for keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked with your code a little and think I found what you might have been looking for using `keyboard.press`.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
from tkinter import *


key = ""

repeatPressCount = 10


def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,1,1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,1,1)



def hold():
    keyboard.press(key)
    print("Typing " + key)
def retrieve():
    global key
    key = key_entry.get()
    print("The key is: " + key)
    try:
        if key != "" and key != " ":
            for i in range(1,repeatPressCount):
                root.after(int(delay_entry.get())*1000, hold())
    except:
        pass
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x450")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

#explains the user what to input
label = Label(frame, text = "input the key u want to be held down. only input a singe key otherwise it wont work" )
label.pack()

#the user inputs the key to be held down
key_entry = Entry(frame, width = 1)
key_entry.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

#explains the user what to input
label2 = Label(frame, text = "input the delay u want. only input a singe digit otherwise it wont work" )
label2.pack()

#the user inputs the time before the key is held down
delay_entry = Entry(frame, width = 2)
delay_entry.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

#the user must press this to send the info 
button = Button(frame, text = "Submit", command = retrieve)
button.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

root.title("why wont this work ")

def exit(event):
    root.destroy()
# press escape to exit
root.bind("<Escape>", exit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me a lot especially the hoverhaul of the retrive function with this i can add a few more features and clean the gui. sry if the question was dumb i dont really get how coding works

Comment: Glad I could help :)